# I am reading Integer from standard input files and have to stop as user stop to enter integers . How this can be done?

Tags: c, stdin

I am writing an algorithm where I take a maximum of 10 inputs. The user is allowed to enter any number of inputs. The problem is I cannot tell the user that at last input you have to enter -1 or anything else. I need to find a mechanism to do this. Does anyone have some advice regarding that?

Comment: Count the number of times you get input and stop when `count == 10`

Comment: Usually, an empty row is used to mean end of input.

Comment: give more details. you wont to read 10 inouts then stop reading ?  "User can enter any number", what does this mean ? you can not stop requiring for inputs ? it is weird.

Comment: suppose there is program of calculating factorial and you are calling that from main(). In Factorial function you have to pass a number that you take I/P from the user in a loop. You allowed user only to enter maximum 10 values , but if  user will enter only two values you  have to calculate factorial for two values. But how will we stop the loop.When will we use break statement? you can take any other int value for breaking through loop. e.g. if( num == -1 ) break ; is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf()` function returns the number of objects it successfully wrote into.
Use that value!

```
int n, a[10];
n = scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", a+0, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4, a+5, a+6, a+7, a+8, a+9);
printf("You entered %d values\n", n);
```

Note for the specific snippet, the user must signal the end of input with some erroneous value (like "42 13 -100 boo") or with EOF ("42 13 -100 CTRL+D CTRL+D"). Just typing ENTERs has no effect: they are ignored by the `"%d"` conversion specification.

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode:

```
get count limit
saturate to 10

start loop (for count-limit times)
scanf
put value to array
end loop
```

or:

```
start loop 
scanf
put value to array
increment counter
check if counter==10 or input is blank then quit
end loop
```